# Listvew with textview and checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I want to have a listview with textview + check box. I was able to create the listview. I can capture listview item select. However when I try to capture check box select, unselect I get a null pointer exception. How to write the setOnCheckedChangeListener() for the check box..

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity{



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.locationmain);

    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " +     DatabaseHandler.TABLE_LOCATIONLABLES;
    SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHandler(this).getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    final List<String> locLables = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(cursor != null){
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                locLables.add(cursor.getString(1));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    //String[] locLables = new String[] {"Home","University","Office"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.locationmain_entry,R.id.textView12, locLables);

    //cb gives a null pointer exception
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) listview.findViewById(R.id.checkBox12);

    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isChecked){
                System.out.println("selected");
            }else if(!isChecked){
                System.out.println("not selected");
            }

        }
    });     
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), locLables.get(arg2), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have a look at these - 1) [listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php) 2) [listview-example-3-simple-multiple-selection-checkboxes](http://appfulcrum.com/2010/09/12/listview-example-3-simple-multiple-selection-checkboxes/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain seperate adpater class so that you can achive this easily....

```
 public class bsAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {
   Activity cntx;
   public bsAdapter(Activity context)
   {
     // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     this.cntx=context;

   }

   public int getCount()
   {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return listview_arr.length;
   }

  public Object getItem(int position)
  {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return listview_arr[position];
  }

  public long getItemId(int position)
  {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return listview_array.length;
  }

  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
     View row=null;

    LayoutInflater inflater=cntx.getLayoutInflater();
    row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list_item, null);

    TextView tv=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);
    CheckBox cb=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.cb01);


    tv.setText(listview_arr[position]);

    cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {

    if(cb.ischecked)
    {
       //ur code
    }

    else //ur code

    }
  });

  return row;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `listview.findViewById()`, just use `findViewById()` like you did for your list.

Unless the checkbox is part of each of the list items, in which case you would have to access the checkbox from within the `getView()` of your `ListAdapter`.

Comment: findViewById() id still gives the error. checkbox is part of each list item. can you explain the getView().. (not in a separate adapter)